# I'm unable to create a credentials instance of ServicePrincipleCredentials from the msrestazure.azure package python

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to connect to an azure keyvault but I can't create the credentials to access any secrets. When I call the code:

```
    TENANT_ID = os.environ.get("key")
    CLIENT = os.environ.get("key")
    KEY = os.environ.get("key")

    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = CLIENT,
        secret = KEY,
        tenant = TENANT_ID
    )
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "file here", line 355, in __init__
    self.set_token()
  File "file here", line 362, in set_token
    super(ServicePrincipalCredentials, self).set_token()
  File "file here", line 188, in set_token
    self._create_adal_context()
  File "file here", line 109, in _create_adal_context
    authority_url = authority_url + '/' + self._tenant
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

I have double checked the keys for correctness any ideas or help is much appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HHammond we have released a new library for KeyVault that is going to make authentication to the service easier (among other things).

You can find the new library on PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault/

Here are some samples that can help you get started: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-keys/samples

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was using older packages that no longer work. msrestazure.azure_active_directory is no longer used I had to use azure.common.credentials